# Pre-load content vs. Ad-Hoc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a lot of content to load inside a hidden `<div>`.  It will be displayed when the user clicks a button.  Should I preload it or do it on the fly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the full details of the scenario, it's impossible to know for sure.

With what you have presented, I'd say it's better to leverage the click action. The reason I say that is because the overhead of querying the DOM is then only applicable for users who click the button instead of on every request to the page.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that's based on (1) how important the information in the said hidden `<div>` is to the end-user and (2) how long it takes to load.  You could always pre-load it if it's a lot of info *(e.g. on `$(document).ready`)*, otherwise just `show()` it on `click()`...